# What does “Last school attended” means?

Tags: phrase-meaning

What does “Last school attended” means?
I have form to fill with this question.
Is it year when I was in school or is it type of school?

The full question is:

> Please fill in the information required by your recruiter. Last school attended:

Comment: It's the name of the school that's required but it might do no harm to say something like: **Graduated from Hill Boys' School in Liverpool**

Comment: to attend school means to go to school.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That might be written out as a full question as follows:

> What is the last school that you attended?

So, that means the school you most recently attended. If the form is intended for adults, it will be your final school.

The trick with forms like this is, I suspect, to think of the label and gap as being a short declarative sentence with a missing verb or preposition, and a space for you to fill in a blank.

> "Last school attended" *was* __________
>
> "Name" *is* ______
>
> "Qualifications" *are* ________

You might want to think of a *your* in front of each one as well.

Comment: Full question is "Please fill in the information required by your recruiter. Last school attended: *"

Comment: When you have a form like that, you can mentally add the relevant words to make it a question. My example would be how that form element should be read.

Comment: @SamBC - I think your interpretation is correct, but it's worth pointing out how a learner might struggle with knowing if the full question would be "**What** is the last school that you attended?" or "**When** was the last time you attended school?" (especially with the way _last_ is often used chronologically).

Comment: Ah, yes. I would expect that the "when" question would be phrased "school last attended" - but that *would* be ambiguous even to a native. The trick is to think of the form fields as declarative statements with missing prepositions or verbs. "Last school attended *was* ___". It would usually be just one word missing, I think. I'll clarify in answer.

Comment: @SamBC Actually, if the *when* version were meant, I think the short form would more likely be *last* ***time*** *attended school*.

Comment: @JasonBassford: Assuming they wanted to avoid ambiguity, sure. Not sure form designers do often have that aim. *Last attended school* is also a possibility.

Answer (score 2):

If you are still studying in college and you need to fill up the form which stated "School last attended" That does mean your previous school before your college school because you are still studying in your current school, it means your secondary school, not your tertiary.